# How to get the Log and Crash data for android live app?

Tags: android, logging, google-analytics, crash, crashlytics

I have developed one android application. Now we are testing this application in production environment.

I have to track the below information with out depending on tester to share the log file,

1. Send Log file. May be Logcat data. Foe Example If any web service fails we need to write that into log file then same needs to be sent to the server or to given mail id.
2. If there is any crash in our app then we can get the stach track by using getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler then we need to send the stack trace info via mail or send it to web server.
3. Or else I can use any solution provider like Google Analytics, Crashlytics or else I can write the log data to text file. And then same to be sent via mail on a daily or weekly basis.

Help me on this.

Comment: Do you have a developer account? You can launch your application as Alpha/Beta and distribute it under testers, while still receiving the crash logs in your dashboard.

Comment: Before uploading the APK into playstore we have to test it inside with our testing team. The testing team will not share that log file every time. Please share the right option to achieve this.

Comment: crashlytics beta thats the best option

Comment: @MVignesh: Are you able to find any solution? My app requires the same type of functionality. We want to get a log file/real-time logs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's about time you move to crashlytics https://try.crashlytics.com/ or critisism http://www.crittercism.com/ check it out, infact there is ton of other options out there

Comment: By using crashlytics how do i get the log information if there is any web service call fails. We can see only the crash data not the log info.

Comment: No in that you will receive email and till date it has not lost any logs maybe delay in sending but that's that

Comment: This will send only when there is crash in our app. Suppose I am trying to get the phone type or imei info. But the phone throws error. There are web services fails always. How do i get the log data which written by me for example failure response from server.

Comment: It logs error also besides if server throws a error exception you could have handled it

Comment: Yes I am handling the server response. How to send that log information web service success or failure to server.

Answer (score 0):

With a service like http://www.apteligent.com (Crittercism renamed to Apteligent), when looking at a crash, you'll be able to automatically see a log of: web service calls, network connectivity changes, changes to screen views, and app foreground/background events that led up to the crash without manually adding any additional logging to your app:

https://www.apteligent.com/2016/03/working-automatic-breadcrumbs/